# MySQL Instrumentation using mysql_proxy

Tags: mysql, windows

I want a simple way to see what commands are being sent to MySQL.  I have several MySQL projects that sometimes have a few messy layers of code.  I want something like [SQL Server Profiler](http://feodorgeorgiev.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/Profiler1.jpg) without all of the bells and whistles.  I just need to see the SQL traffic.  Not analyze which queries are executed most often.

I found [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/proxy-gettingstarted.html) and can't get it to work in Windows.  I downloaded their binaries, and tried their first example LUA script from the link.  It loads fine, but when I try to connect to port 4040 using mysql, I get:

```
ERROR 1105 (HY000): #07000MySQL Proxy Lua script failed to load. Check the error log.
```

What error log?  I didn't even give it the credentials to connect to my real SQL Server.  What can I do to get this to work?  I'm open to other options (hopefully not sniffing traffic, but maybe if someone can make it easy).

Comment: How is Java related to this question? Seems more a software problem (which rather belongs at superuser.com or maybe serverfault.com) than a programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable query logging in my.ini. this will write all queries to a log file

add the line

```
log = [querylog_filename]
```

Then restart the mysql service

using a program such as tail for win http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/ will allow you to watch the queries as they run.

if you have a problematic query you can enable slow logging as well. which will log important details about queries that take a long time to run

DC

Comment: Perfect answer.  I was trying to use binlog earlier but was very frustrated with parsing the file format.  From the documentation, I believed the only difference from binlog and log was that binlog masked out selects.  I didn't realize log was in a simple plaintext format.  tailforwin32 is a great find.  I also noticed that MySQL Administrator can also show the log (but you have to constantly refresh).  Thanks again!